# Custom hooks are called infinitely when used with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, swr

While refactoring the code to fetch account information, there was a problem that the page was rerendered indefinitely.

This is my custom hook to fetch account information.

```js
//flattenTree returns an array of flattened Object that has children.
const flattenTree = <T extends { children: T[] }>(treeObject: T) => {
  const flattenedTree: T[] = []
  flattenedTree.push(treeObject)
  const queue = [treeObject]
  while (queue.length !== 0) {
    const searching = queue.shift()
    for (const child of searching?.children || []) {
      flattenedTree.push(child)
      queue.push(child)
    }
  }
  return flattenedTree
}


const useFetchAccounts = () => {
  const [accountsA, setAccountsA] = useState([])
  const [accountsB, setAccountsB] = useState([])
  const [accountIdsA, setAccountIdsA] = useState(new Set())
  const [accountIdsB, setAccountIdsB] = useState(new Set())

  const { data: accountTreeA } = useSWR(
    `${FETCH_ACCOUNT_URL}/${ACCOUNTA_ID}`,
    fetchAccount
  )
  const { data: accountTreeB } = useSWR(
    `${FETCH_ACCOUNT_URL}/${ACCOUNTB_ID}`,
    fetchAccount
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (accountTreeA) {
      setAccountsA(flattenTree(accountTreeA))
    }
  }, [accountTreeA])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (accountTreeB) {
      setAccountsB(flattenTree(accountTreeB))
    }
  }, [accountTreeB])

  useEffect(() => {
    setAccountIdsA(new Set(accountsA.map((account) => account.accountId)))
  }, [accountsA])
  useEffect(() => {
    setAccountIdsB(new Set(accountsB.map((account) => account.accountId)))
  }, [accountsB])

  return {
    accounts: {
      accountsA,
      accountsB,
    },
    accountIds: {
      accountIdsA,
      accountIdsB,
    },
  }
}
```

And this is the component that uses the custom hook above.

```js
const TestPage: React.FC = () => {
  const [accountsC, setAccountsC] = useState<Account[]>([])
  const [accountIdsC, setAccountIdsC] = useState<Set<string>>(new Set())
  const [pageC, setPageC] = useState<LongShortPage[]>([])
  const { accounts, accountIds } = useFetchAccounts()

  const { data: pageA } = useSWR(
    {
      url: FETCH_BOOK_BY_ACCOUNT_ID,
      targetAccountIds: [...accountIds.accountIdsA],
    },
    fetchPagesByAccountIds
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    const { accountsA } = accounts
    const { accountIdsA, accountIdsB } = accountIds
    setAccountsC(accountsA.filter((account) => !accountIdsB.has(account.accountId)))
    setAccountIdsC(
      new Set([...accountIdsA].filter((accountId) => !accountIdsB.has(accountId)))
    )
  }, [accounts, accountIds])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pageA) {
      setPageC(pageA.filter((page) => accountIdsC.has(page.accountId)))
    }
  }, [pageA, accountIdsC])

  return (
    <li>
      {[...accountIdsC].map((id) => (
        <div key={id}>${id}</div>
      ))}
      {/*
      elision
      */}
    </li>
  )
}
```

It seems that useFetchAccounts is called infinitely and because of that my component renders infinitely.

So, I thought there was a problem with how to use the custom hook, and moved all the logic inside the custom hook into the component, and the problem was solved.

Why did that happen?

And how modify or refactor the code?

This is an codesandbox example that reproduces the problem.

[image: Edit msw-react-example (forked)]

Comment: Check if custom hook return values are changing. If values are the same if you print but in return, you generate a new object so it will find the object is changed. To avoid you need to memorize values using useMemo.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar If you don't mind, can you give me an example using my code where I can use useMemo?

Comment: Yes, do you have a sample running version in codesandbox/stackblitz? It will be easier to apply other solutions if possible and give you a working sample.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar Added codesandbox that reproduces the problem to the question.

Comment: I have checked the codesandbox. I can see useFetchUser is displayed multiple times but its not calling infinite. I have added useMemo https://codesandbox.io/s/msw-react-example-forked-660r1z?file=/src/useFetchUser.js

Comment: @DhavalGajjar yeah, I don't know why, but it seems I have failed to fully reproduce the problem. But your solution works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` to memorize the values. As you return an object with {} so it will assume the object has changed to a new location.

```
return useMemo(
  () => ({
  accounts: {
    accountsA,
    accountsB,
  },
  accountIds: {
    accountIdsA,
    accountIdsB,
  },
}), [accountsA, accountsB, accountIdsA, accountIdsB]);
```

Updating answer from the comment in question.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the useEffect because when you use it and specify the next for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (accountTreeA) {
      //Flatten a tree object that has children
      setAccountsA(flattenTree(accountTreeA))
    }
  }, [accountTreeA])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (accountTreeB) {
      setAccountsB(flattenTree(accountTreeB))
    }
  }, [accountTreeB])
```

It will be called when **accountTreeA** and **accountTreeB** change. If you for example use, a useEffect with accountTreeA and inside the useEffect update the value with setAccountTreeA you are doing an infinite loop because it will be updating all time.

I don't know if I'm explaining well, but I want to tell you that useEffect is listening when accountTreeA or B has new updates to be called another time.

I hope that this information helps you.

Kind regards,
Fernando

Comment: I'm not changing `accountTreeA` inside useEffect.
`accountTreeA` is fetched from some api, and inside useEffect, `accountsA` that flatten AccountTreeA is updated.

Of course, useEffect will be called infinitely, but before that, a custom hook called `useFetchAccounts` is called infinitely.

Comment: Hi, try to add the onFetch function inside the useEffect, and instead of putting [accountTreeA] put [], it will only call 1 time.